# When value that is not Copy gets moved, what happens to the raw pointers that point to the moved value? (Rust)

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, heap-memory, stack-memory

Check TLDR at the bottom if you are not interested in me rambling about stuff I don't understand :).

I am trying to implement A-star pathfinding alg in Rust.
Just a basic version. I don't want to use `Rc` and my nodes store `*const` (raw pointer) to previous `Node` (`prev: const* Node`) so that I can retrieve the shortest path (solution).

```
struct Node {
    position: Position,
    // NonNull also works I guess
    previous: Option<*const Node>
}
```

Also I am using `PriorityQueue` ([crate link](https://crates.io/crates/priority-queue)) where I store my nodes. My knowledge is very limited regarding memory management and low-level stuff.

Okay now I will first talk a bit what happens inside my program to better clarify what I am asking.

To my understanding, my nodes get stored/**moved** into `PriorityQueue` that is actually a `HashMap`.

`PriorityQueue` -> `...` -> `Vec<Bucket<K, V>>` -> `Bucket { hash: HashValue, key: K, value: V }`

So they get stored on the `heap`, but the thing is that my nodes first get created on `stack` (I never heap allocate them using `Box`, or their lifetime is just bound to the stack I guess?).

Then their `previous` field gets assigned a raw pointer to the previous node `*const Node` and then they get **moved**/pushed in the `vector` that is returned from the function (now they are on the heap).

> **Nodes**:  `stack` -> `Vec`

Code of function that returns that `Vec`:

```
fn neighbours(&self, maze: &Maze) -> Vec<Node> {
    let offset_x: [isize; 8] = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1];
    let offset_y: [isize; 8] = [0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1];

    let mut neighbours = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..8 {
        let nx = self.position.x() + offset_x[i];
        let ny = self.position.y() + offset_y[i];

        if Node::is_valid((nx, ny), maze) {
            let (nx, ny) = (nx as usize, ny as usize);

            let mut node = Node::new(Position((nx, ny)), self, maze.end().unwrap());

            node.previous = Some(self as *const _);
            neighbours.push(node);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    neighbours
}
```

Keep in mind that `previous` node is on **stack** when we assign raw pointer to it (`*const Node`) to our newly created nodes. (Also sidenote, the `Previous` node was originally popped from `PriorityQueue` and **moved** into a variable on a `stack`)

> **Previous:** `stack`

After that, (nodes) from that vector they get **moved** into `PriorityQueue` we will call this queue `open` (or just get dropped but that is not important).

> **Nodes:** `Vec` -> `open: PriorityQueue`

So far so good because `Previous` node is not yet moved and the raw pointer should still point to it.

But after those nodes get into `PriorityQueue` the `Previous` node gets **moved** also into the other `PriorityQueue` lets call that queue `closed`.

> **Previous:** `stack` -> `closed: PriorityQueue`

Now my question finally is, what happens to the raw pointer that pointed to the previous nodes, is this undefined behaviour, meaning that now pointer is no longer pointing to that allocation?

**TLDR**:

How memory works when non Copy value gets moved (is it still on the same memory address)? Does only the ownership of the value changes and the value stays on the same memory address, or it changes memory address, gets new memory allocation and just gets copied there?
If this might be a bit too general, what happens to my `Node` struct then when it gets **moved**, will those pointers that point to `previous` `Node` that got moved be invalid?

Comment: Your struct _may_ change address or not when it is moved depending on compiler version and optimization level. Whether it changes or not, your pointers will _not_ be actualized, so you have to assume that they are made invalid when the struct is moved.

Comment: If you do not want to use `Rc` consider storing your nodes in a backup storage, such as a [slotmap](https://crates.io/crates/slotmap), and use keys instead of pointers. All your unsafe blocks will magically disappear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a node is moved, it as actually stored somewhere else, thus its address is not the same (in general, even if some optimisations could prevent that, but nothing is guaranteed).

The minimal example below shows this; the initial nodes are created on the stack, then we move them into the heap-allocated storage of a vector.
Displaying the address of all these nodes shows that these addresses are not the same indeed.

The `previous` member of `n1`, initialised with the address of `n0` when it was on the stack, becomes a dangling pointer as soon as `n0` is moved to the vector.
The location of `n0` could have been reused for some other variables, and **what happens when accessing this memory location through the pointer is actually undefined**.

That's why dereferencing a raw pointer is an `unsafe` operation in Rust (and that's also probably why Rust exists).

Independently of the `Copy` trait, the difference between copying a value and moving a value is subtle.
In this case, `Node` is only made of basic types (an integer and a raw pointer, eventually null if `None`) and does *not* perform memory management with this pointer (as `Vec` does with the pointer it contains).
Thus, moving a `Node` happens to be physically the same thing as copying it: more or less a bitwise copy of the members of the struct as if `Node` was `Copy`.

When it comes to a `Vec` that we would like to move for example, the move operation would have been much more interesting.
The new location of the `Vec` (where it is moved-to) keeps the pointer (bitwise copy) to the heap-allocated storage as known in the initial location (where it is moved-from).
Then, this moved-from location is not considered anymore to be the owner of this heap-allocated storage: we have transferred ownership of the heap-allocated storage between the moved-from and moved-to locations, but we did not have to duplicate this heap-allocated storage.
This is the main interest of the move operation over the copy/clone (saving the duplication of heap-allocated storage by simply transferring ownership).
This situation is visible in the example below, when `nodes` is moved to `nodes_again`: the `Vec` itself is moved, but the `Node`s it contains are not.
[This section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html?highlight=move#memory-and-allocation) of « The Rust Programming Language » explains very well this situation, using a `String` instead of a `Vec`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    previous: Option<*const Node>,
}

fn main() {
    let n0 = Node {
        value: 0,
        previous: None,
    };
    let n1 = Node {
        value: 1,
        previous: Some(&n0 as *const _),
    };
    println!("n0 at {:?}: {:?}", &n0 as *const _, n0);
    println!("n1 at {:?}: {:?}", &n1 as *const _, n1);
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    let nodes = vec![n0, n1];
    println!("nodes at {:?}", &nodes as *const _);
    for (i, n) in nodes.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("nodes[{}] at {:?}: {:?}", i, n as *const _, n);
    }
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    let nodes_again = nodes;
    println!("nodes_again at {:?}", &nodes_again as *const _);
    for (i, n) in nodes_again.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("nodes_again[{}] at {:?}: {:?}", i, n as *const _, n);
    }
}
/*
n0 at 0x7ffd2dd14520: Node { value: 0, previous: None }
n1 at 0x7ffd2dd14500: Node { value: 1, previous: Some(0x7ffd2dd14520) }
~~~~~~~~
nodes at 0x7ffd2dd144e8
nodes[0] at 0x558bad50fba0: Node { value: 0, previous: None }
nodes[1] at 0x558bad50fbb8: Node { value: 1, previous: Some(0x7ffd2dd14520) }
~~~~~~~~
nodes_again at 0x7ffd2dd14490
nodes_again[0] at 0x558bad50fba0: Node { value: 0, previous: None }
nodes_again[1] at 0x558bad50fbb8: Node { value: 1, previous: Some(0x7ffd2dd14520) }
*/
```